# Manipulation with large dimensional matrix in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the following function for each row of a matrix M of dimension 3e+07x4.

```
func <- function(x){

   (dmultinom(c(x[c(1,2)],50-sum(x[c(1,2)])), size = NULL, rep(1/3,3), log = FALSE))/(x[3]^2+x[4]^3)

}
```

I am using the following code

```
as.numeric(unlist(apply(M, 1, function(v) func(v))))
```

Unfortunately, it is taking a long time. I'd like to do this in a short time.

Comment: I don't think you can be much faster than this. There is other "apply" functions that might be faster in this particular instance, but it's not gonna be by much. Check out `map` from the `tidyverse` for example.
My suggestion: if you need this only once, just wait. If you need it more often and really need it to be fast, you might be able to speed it up by translating it into `C++` code. You can get into this topic, e.g., here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html.

Comment: It might be possible to see some improvements if split over multiple cores with something like `foreach::foreach` or `plyr::daply` with the `.parallel` argument set.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, `lgamma` is a Primitive function and hence an option is to vectorize `dmultinom` by yourself. Here is a option combined with `data.table` for faster sped

```
set.seed(0L)
nr <- 3e7 #3e7
size <- 50L
DT <- data.table(X1=sample(1:20, nr, TRUE), X2=sample(1:20, nr, TRUE), X3=3, X4=4)

system.time({
    DT[, paste0("lgX", 1L:3L) := c(lapply(1+.SD, lgamma), .(lgamma(1+size-X1-X2))), .SDcols=X1:X2][,
       dmn := exp(lgamma(size + 1L) + log(1/3) * size - (lgX1 + lgX2 + lgX3)) / (X3^2 + X4^2)]
    DT$dmn
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   7.44    0.17    7.64
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, but I haven't verified the correctness.  Your:

```
func <- function(x) {
  (dmultinom(c(x[c(1,2)],50-sum(x[c(1,2)])), size = NULL, rep(1/3,3), log = FALSE))/(x[3]^2+x[4]^3)
}
```

can be written as:

```
func <- function(x) {
  a <- x[c(1,2)]
  b <- 50 - (a[1] + a[2])
  d <- c(a, b)
  e <- dmultinom(d, size = NULL, rep(1/3,3), log = FALSE)
  f <- x[3]^2 + x[4]^3
  e / f
}
```

The `d` part you can vectorize via matrix calculations as:

```
A <- M[, 1:2]
B <- 50 - (A[,1] + A[,2])
D <- cbind(A, B)
```

Without diving into `dmultinom()`, the `e` part can be calculated via `apply()` as:

```
prob <- rep(1/3, times = 3L)
E <- apply(D, MARGIN = 1L, function(d) {
  dmultinom(d, size = NULL, prob = prob, log = FALSE)
})
```

The `f` part you can vectorize via matrix calculations as:

```
F <- M[,3]^2 + M[,4]^3
```

which gives that:

```
Y <- apply(M, 1, function(v) func(v))
```

can be written as:

```
Y <- E / F
```

Disclaimer: Haven't verified but you should get the idea of how to vectorize and avoid duplicate things.

PS. If you look at `dmultinom()`, I think you can vectorize that as well in a similar fashion.  It's not unlikely that you can get rid of the remaining `apply()` call.